# Combining two string and insert element VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I tried to build a combination algorithm between 2 strings, unfortunately it has some errors.

```
Dim strWordsA() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(",")
Dim strWordsB() As String = TextBox2.Text.Split(",")
        Dim str As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim arr As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(","c)
        For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.Text.Split(",").Length - 1
            Dim index As Integer = str.IndexOf(strWordsA(i))
            TextBox1.Text = str.Insert(index + 2, "," & strWordsB(i))
            str = TextBox1.Text
        Next
```

so if we have `Textbox1.Text` = `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` and `Textbox2.Text` = `a,b,c,f,d,b,i,h,` and so on... I need to display this in a 3rd textbox

Textbox3.Text = `1,a,2,b,3,c,4,f and so on`

so do I combine these 2 strings?

the first element in the index displays it incorrectly, otherwise it seems to work ok.

Comment: Why are you splitting `TextBox.Text` three different times?

Comment: because I don't know how to use that string that is split, it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Function MergeStrings(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String

    Dim strWordsA() As String = s1.Split(","c)
    Dim strWordsB() As String = s2.Split(","c)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim OutputString As String = String.Empty
    While i < strWordsA.Length OrElse i < strWordsB.Length
        If i < strWordsA.Length Then OutputString &= "," & strWordsA(i)
        If i < strWordsB.Length Then OutputString &= "," & strWordsB(i)
        i += 1
    End While
    If Not OutputString = String.Empty Then Return OutputString.Substring(1)
    Return OutputString

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim s As String = MergeStrings("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9", "a,b,c,f,d,b,i,h")
```

You will need to add your own validation to allow for trailing commas or no commas etc but it should work with different length input strings

EDIT: amended as per Mary's comment

Comment: Turn on Option Strict now and always. When you do, you will see that you need to add `c` to `Split(",")`  `Split(","c)` This tells the compiler that you intend a Char not a String.

Comment: Thank you very much Jon Roberts and Mary for your help and the fact that I learned a lot!